# Alternating groups as galois groups

Tags: galois-theory

Is there an elementary proof that the alternating group $A_n$, for any $n$, is the Galois group of an extension of the rationals? In fact, I am looking for a proof which does not use Hilbert's irreducibility theorem. This can be done for $S_n$ by establishing the existence of an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb Z[X]$, of degree $n$, whose Galois group over the rationals contains a transposition and an $(n-1)$-cycle. I have been wondering whether an analogous proof could be found for $A_n$.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you know of any non-elementary proofs of the result, so that people can decide what would be acceptable and what is not?

Comment: For instance, is your goal to avoid the use of Hilbert's irreducibility theorem?

Comment: It is a well-known problem: essentially, it boils down to finding an irreducible polynomial with a square discriminant, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem

Comment: @Jack: that only shows that the Galois group is contained in $A_n$.